# Opening an XML file and highlighting a specific line

Tags: xml, database, vb.net

In visual basic I have created a database utility that does the following: Takes in a string to 'find' then it searches an entire netwrok drive of xml files containing that specific line of text. If the given text is found, I list the file path in a listview and you can double click to open the file.

All of that works perfectly as is. What I want to the software to do is when the user double clicks the file path and opens the file, I would like the line of text that was found to be highlighted right there for the user.

Is there any built-in utility in VB that would allow me to do that?

Thank you.

***Edit

The software loads the xml externally. Whatever the user has set as the default program for xml files is what gets loaded. Ideally the solution would allow me to continue doing this, but hey, maybe a rtb is the right option.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you included whether you're using winforms or wpf, and also what control you're using to show the file's text...those all have an effect on what methods are available to highlight a line. It might also help to add any relevant existing code, but definitely need to know what is being used to display the text

Comment: This can easily be done if the file is opening in your program however if it is opening in Notepad or another texteditor then that editor will need to have a feature where you can send arguments such as a filename and a line to highlight.

Comment: @soohoonigan This is a winforms application used in my place of employment. For this reason I feel it is irresponsible of me to copy paste in the code. I understand this makes my question 10x harder. However, I'm not looking for a solution necessarily, but options that VB has for this.

Comment: Inside winforms, I think RTB is going to be your best bet. I'm not sure doing it externally will be possible, unless the app you're using supports some kind of messaging service or command line parameters

Comment: @soohoonigan Its looking more and more impossible as the hours go on. Another issue is that there is no text editor standard here. Therefore i there were to be some sort of external command sent to the editor it would not work for everyone. This is such a minuscule functionality to add, but I like things to be perfect...

Comment: It that's the case, then that makes adding a RichTextBox to your app an even more appealing option

Answer (score 1):

For the RichTextBox option here is an example:

```vb
Public Sub SelectLine(ByVal lineIndex As Integer)
   MyRichTextBox1.HideSelection = False

   If lineIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
   If lineIndex > MyRichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then Exit Sub

   MyRichTextBox1.SelectionStart = MyRichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineIndex)
   MyRichTextBox1.SelectionLength = MyRichTextBox1.Lines(lineIndex).Length 
End Sub
```

*Note: lineIndex is zero based. Also this assumes this sub is on a form with MyRichTextBox1.*    [See this link for another example and the code on which this is based.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d03705a-01b2-4135-8a26-f84411169c9c/highlight-a-specific-line-in-a-richtextbox-visual-basic-net-express-2010?forum=Vsexpressvb)